# Is there a Python SDK for Azure Synapse?

Tags: python, azure, sdk, azure-synapse

I'm new to into Azure world!

I'm looking for a Python SDK for Synapse to execute queries (something like google-cloud-bigquery for GCP BigQuery) but I'm not finding anything useful, only an azure-synapse library on pypi that is deprecated.

Is there something similar to a Synapse Client or is it possible to access only via PySpark in Python?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

https://pypi.org/project/azure-synapse/. It does say "It is deprecated", but think that's in reference to the previous sentence "This package was the Microsoft Azure Synapse bundle.". Believe this is latest and greatest.